# allowing web url access into phonegap android application

Tags: android, cordova

I want know where to tell android phonegap cordova  to allow access to all external url.

I know i have to do it in cordova.xml but am running cordova 3.0 and there is no file
called cordova.xml in my application.

The only xml file i could find is 
AndroidManifest.xml
Build.xml

Answer (score 0):

The whitelisting rules are found in res/xml/config.xml and declared with the element .

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide